# Modular Algorithm calculation error

Tags: c++

I have a program use Modular Exponentiation to calculate 7^644 mod 645, 11^644 mod 645, 3^2003 mod 99, 123^1001 mod 101. I follow the rules of Modular Exponentiation and then when I compile my result is wrong, The result for the output should be 436,1,22,27, but my output is way off. when i run my answer is 643, 655,20,39

This is My code:

```
int Modulo(int b, int e, int m)
{

int remainder;//set the remainder of the procedure
int x = 1;// modular initially sets x = 1

//while loop to request the multiplication
while ( e != 0)
{

    remainder = e % 2;
    e = e/2;

    //Algorithm steps
    if(remainder == 1)//if remainder = 1 
    x = ( x * b) % m;//then x = (x · power) % m
    b = ( b * b) % m;//power = (power * power) % m

}
return x;


}
int main()
 {

  int b, e, m, modulo;//declares the variables 
  start:cout<<"Enter the base: ";//output for base
  cin>>b;

  cout<<"Enter the exponent: ";//output for exponent
  cin>>e;

  cout<<"Enter the number of modular: ";//output for mod
  cin>>m;

  modulo = b^e % m;//requesting the formula of Modular Exponentiation
  cout<<"The answer is \n"<<modulo<<endl;
  cin.get();
  // I create if statement to allow the user to restart the application 
//enter new value to see the different output
    char c;
    cout<<"Would you like to enter a new value? yes or no ";
    cin>> c;
    if(( c == 'Y') ||(c == 'y'))goto start ;//start is the label in the start of program
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Uhhh... You do realize that you're not using your `Modulo` function, right?

Comment: If you use your function, does it work?

Comment: I think the function is calculate differently it didn't function as the program shows

Comment: `x^y` **is not** a power operation but bitwise XOR

Comment: XOR? I never use that before

Comment: [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Comment: So the operation I did for my program are the XOR operation? Not Modulo?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'd write the code something like this (tested and produces correct results at least for the values I've tried):

```
unsigned Modulo(unsigned b, unsigned e, unsigned m) {
    unsigned x = 1;

    while (e > 0) {
        if (e & 1)
            x = x * b % m;
        e >>= 1;
        b = b * b % m;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Note that I've tried to use the same names as your code did -- many of them don't strike me as the best (or even very good) choices though. `Modulo` seems to me like a particularly poor name. I'd prefer something like `pow_mod` that at least hints at what it's doing (where `Modulo` is pretty much outright misleading).